# Apache httpd terminates on interrupt/breakpoint

Tags: linux, gdb, valgrind, apache

I try to use "valgrind --vgdb=yes httpd -X" to debug a service running via httpd, and monitor memory leaks using "monitor leak_check full reachable increased" after each request. The problem is that I cannot interrupt httpd reliably in order to run the "monitor" command in gdb - when I press Ctrl-C in valgrind/httpd terminal, it usually terminates, same when I send kill -INT. I tried different "handle SIGINT/SIGTERM nopass/pass" but with no luck.

Also often, when I just add breakpoints and pause httpd in Eclipse CDT/gdb debugger, httpd terminates, too.

So is it possible to interrupt httpd without making it exit in 90% cases?

Comment: Interesting. I have certainly debugged Apache with gdb (though not with vgdb) many times on RHEL and similar systems. Perhaps it's a valgrind's bug. Are you using the newest version of gdb? The older ones can be a bit flaky.

Comment: I use gdb that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 (7.4). Maybe it's valgrind bug but then why it also terminates when run in Eclipse. The service that I debug is built around axis2/c, I wonder if this can also be the reason.